# How to check if a Worksheet contains a specific macro

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

In my little C# Programm im opening up an Excel sheet using Excel Interop to run a macro inside the sheet:

```
xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFullPath(path).Replace("\"", ""));
xlApp.Application.Run(Macro: macroName);
```

Im just passing the Macro as a string `macroName`from a user input.
Unfortunately the programm crashes, if the macro doesnt exist in the current active worksheet.
Is there a way i can check for the macro before trying to run it, to give a suitable response to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975719/11840666). This solution works perfectly fine for me, thanks to Fredrik.